# installing windows service from command line "The specified service has been marked for deletion"

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I am trying to create a batch file to automate uninstalling, building and reinstalling a windows service.
After uninstalling when I try to reinstall I get the error: The specified service has been marked for deletion.

here is the batch script:

```
@ECHO off
set filePath=<myfilepath>
set serviceName=<myservicename>
sc query %serviceName% > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 net stop %serviceName% & sc delete %serviceName%
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\TFS\MOC\LaneUpdateService\LaneUpdateService.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe %filePath%
sc start %serviceName%
```

I do not have task manager, services or event viewer open, there are no other users logged in. I have tried deleting the reg key for my service, with no luck. If I run my script again after it failing it will install correctly. Is there a way to manually make sure the service is fully deleted?

Comment: Eh, so you don't *trust* `sc delete` will finish off the service or what?

Comment: You probably just need to wait for a short period before attempting the install.  In a loop, preferably, using `sc query` to check whether the deletion has completed.  (But note that it might not be necessary to delete the service before running the install.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that after stopping my service there was still a process running. I altered my onstop method to make sure all processes were stopped correctly. now the batch file works correctly. As @Harry Johnston suggested I will be adding a while loop to the batch file.